# A possible test case I am missing out on?

Tags: c

**Problem statement**

[image]

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int T;
    scanf("%d",&T);
    for(int i=0;i<T;i++)
    {
        int N,K;
        scanf("%d %d",&N,&K);
        if(K!=0 && N>K)
        {
            printf("%d \n", (N%K));
        }
        else if(N<K)
        {
            printf("%d \n", N);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("0 \n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now this is giving me the correct answer for the test case they have specified, but when I submit this, it doesn't get accepted. I know I am missing out on a test case which is not verified through the above code, but I am unable to wrap my head around it. Any help would be really appreciated!

The site demographics show that quite a few users missed out on something, because usually when I'm doing questions at codechef, the accuracy is mostly above 60 at the least.

[image]

Comment: Can you copy&paste the problem statement into the question body? That would make the question much more readable.

Comment: For one thing, only output a trailing space *if the problem tells you to*. There is a robot checking the answers. But it says "print a single line containing one integer".

Comment: Always check the return value of `scanf()`

Comment: I just asked two questions which were heavily downvoted (I don't know why?) and now I am not allowed to ask more questions. Why? Is there any way to solve this issue?

Comment: I find this so demotivating :( I am just a beginner, you can't expect beginners to know everything :/

Comment: Thanks to everyone who spent time to answer this question. I understood where i was making a mistake

Comment: @apocalyptic Don't worry... I guess you were downvoted at first because you didn't manage to show the pictures in the question and only had links to the pics. Now you know that pictures can be shown so next time you'll do better. Don't worry... be happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your solution is that this code

```
    {
        printf("0 \n");
    }
```

will be executed in two situations:

1. When K equals N
2. When K is 0 (zero)

For number 1 the result will be 0 (zero) so that is correct.

For number 2 the result will be N so that is your bug.

For the complete solution I would simply do:

```
printf("&d\n", (K == 0) ? N : N%K);
```

No need for the nested `if`-statements. You don't need a special handling of `N < K`

Answer (score 1):

If `K` is zero, the result needs to be `N`.  But the unnecessary checks after the first `if` break this by forcing the result to `0`.  You can fix it by eliminating those unnecessary checks.  You also don't need to check if `N>K`, since the result will be the same even if it isn't.  All you need is:

```
if(K!=0)
{
    printf("%d \n", N%K);
}
else
{
    printf("%d \n", N);
}
```

Independent of this, I'm not sure why the trailing spaces are there.  You might want to eliminate those as well (do they check for it?)  You can also shorten it by using `?:` as shown below.  Also note that by reversing the order of the two cases, the explicit comparison of `K` with zero can be eliminated as well:

```
printf("%d\n", K ? N%K : N);
```

That's the all you need after the `scanf`.  You don't need any `if` statements at all.  If `K` is zero, it prints `N`.  Otherwise it removes as many multiples of `K` as possible, which is just `N%K`.